# Using AWS Cognito for Hasura authentication with multiple user pools

Tags: authentication, jwt, amazon-cognito, hasura

I'm following along the [AWS Cognito auth guide here](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/guides/integrations/aws-cognito.html#set-up-user-pools-and-hosted-web-ui) to set up a Lambda authorizer for our Hasura API. It's working nicely for a single user pool, but we'd like to do it using multiple pools.

In the [Configure Hasura to use Cognito keys](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/guides/integrations/aws-cognito.html#configure-hasura-to-use-cognito-keys) step, `HASURA_GRAPHQL_JWT_SECRET` is built using the `<user-pool-id>` so it's kinda linked to a single AWS Cognito user pool, I'm wondering if there's a way to set it up so that the same lambda function can be used to authenticate multiple user pools without deploying a separate Hasura instance per user pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue for supporting Multiple User Pools - https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/2208#issuecomment-640216358

The only proposed workaround is using webhooks instead of JWT - https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/auth/authentication/webhook.html